# Can we give a name attribute in <img> in HTML

Tags: html, image, attributes

Is the "name" attribute can given in an "img" tag in HTML?

Kindly let me know if whoever knows and thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you intend to do with such an attribute? Note that you can always add "data-*" attributes for any additional information that you wish to access from JavaScript (such as "data-name"). If you want a name for accessibility, you are probably thinking of the "alt" attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can give **name** attribute to image , but instead of giving **name** attribute, i suggest use **data-name**. It is good habit to give private use of attribute name.

Comment: I have applied the "custom tag" instead of "name attribute" ~thank u :)

Comment: +1 Whoever downvoted this doesn't know what they're talking about. `data-name` is the best approach in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

**No. You *cannot<sup>1</sup>*** have such attribute.

<sup>1</sup>The *`name` attribute* on the `<img>` tag is **deprecated** since HTML4.1 and **obsolete** since HTML5.
Use `id` or `data-*` attribute instead (like: `data-name="whatever"`) if you need custom attributes.

---

### `<img>` Attributes

- `align` **Deprecated since HTML4.01, Obsolete since HTML5** Use the vertical-align CSS
- `alt`
- `border` **Deprecated since HTML4.01, Obsolete since HTML5**
- `crossorigin` (HTML5)
- `height`
- `hspace` **Deprecated since HTML4.01, Obsolete since HTML5**
- `ismap`
- `longdesc`
- `name` **Deprecated since HTML4.01, Obsolete since HTML5** Use `id` or `data-*`
- `referrerpolicy`
- `sizes` (HTML5)
- `src`
- `srcset` (HTML5)
- `width`
- `usemap`
- `vspace` **Deprecated since HTML4.01, Obsolete since HTML5**

<sub>https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using alt, here is an example:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```