# Loop images on hover - setInterval issue

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

My code is running well...
but there is one thing I can't solve:
when I `mouseover` the image the loop starts well, but on subsequent mouseovers it starts changing faster and faster...

```js
var Image = new Array("//placehold.it/400x180/?text=Welcome",
                     "//placehold.it/400x180/?text=To",
                     "//placehold.it/400x180/?text=My",
                     "//placehold.it/400x180/?text=Web+page",
                     "//placehold.it/400x180/?text=INPHP");

var Image_Number=0;
var Image_Length= Image.length;

function change_image(num){
  Image_Number = Image_Number + num;
  if(Image_Number > Image_Length)
    Image_Number = 0;
  if(Image_Number < Image_Length)
    document.slideshow.src = Image[Image_Number];
  return false;
  Image_Number = Image_Length;
}

function auto () {
  setInterval("change_image(1)", 1000);
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/400x180/?text=Welcome" name="slideshow" onmouseover="auto()" />
```

Comment: I like it - just call it a feature

Comment: @AndrewMairose funny but irrelevant and unhelpful comment. (LOLd so much :D )

Comment: @downvoters, please, the OP provided all the coded he has done so far and the question is pretty understandable. Show some sportmanship.

Answer (score 0):

On every `mouseover` you're reassigning a brand-new-interval™ resulting in multiple functions running at the same time.

- `name` on IMG tag is an [obsolete HTML5 attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36873460/383904) - See also [img tag @ W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html)
- `"change_image(1)"` ...strings inside `setInterval` or `setTimeout` tigger `eval`. Which is bad. The real *function name* should be used instead: `setInterval(functionName, ms)`
- You're not managing well the argument `num`
- You cannot have code after a `return` statement
- Use the `mouseenter` event (instead of `mouseover`)
- and many more errors....

**Here's a remake:**

```js
var images = [
  "//placehold.it/400x180/?text=Welcome",
  "//placehold.it/400x180/?text=To",
  "//placehold.it/400x180/?text=My",
  "//placehold.it/400x180/?text=Web+page",
  "//placehold.it/400x180/?text=INPHP"
];
var c = 0; // c as Counter ya?
var tot = images.length;
var angryCat = false;

// Preload! Make sure all images are in tha house
for(var i=0; i<tot; i++) {
  var im = new Image();
  im.src= images[i];
}

function changeImage() {
  document.slideshow.src = images[++c%tot];
}

function auto() {
  if(angryCat) return; // No more mouse enter
  angryCat = true;
  setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/400x180/?text=Welcome" name="slideshow" onmouseenter="auto()" />
```

The increment and loop is achieved using `++c % tot`
The `angryCat` boolean flag helps to know it the `auto()` already started (mouse was there!), in that case it will `return;` (exit) the function preventing the creation of additional overlapping intervals on subsequent mouseenter (which was your main issue).

---

Additionally, I'd suggest to keep your JS away from HTML, so instead of the JS attribute event

```
onmouseenter="auto()"
```

assign an ID to your image `id="myimage"` and use JS:

```
document.getElementById("myimage").addEventListener("mouseenter", auto, false);
```

Comment: Thanks all for your answer's ,,,, 
it's was so helpful ... 
even LOL made my day :) thx :)